# sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (pymysql.err.DataError) (1406, "Data too long for column 'password' at row 1")

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

```
def create_user(db: Session, user: UserCreate):
    hashed_password= bcrypt.hashpw(user.password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
    db_user= User(email=user.email, password=hashed_password, lname=user.lname, fname=user.fname)
    print('---->', db_user)
    db.add(db_user)
    db.commit()
    return db_user

@app.post('/api/users', response_model= User)
def signup(user_data: UserCreate, db: Session= Depends(get_db)):
    user= get_user_by_email(db, user_data.email)
    if user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=409,
                                detail="Email already registered")
    signedup_user = create_user(db, user_data)
    print("--------->", signedup_user)
    return signedup_user
```

sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (pymysql.err.DataError) (1406, "Data too long for column 'password' at row 1")
[SQL: INSERT INTO users (lname, fname, email, password) VALUES (%(lname)s, %(fname)s, %(email)s, %(password)s)]
[parameters: {'lname': 'stsdf', 'fname': 'swef', 'email': 'didou@gmail.com', 'password': b'$2b$12$nui9RJwoVkU.h6d9ASw6POLZhbn83YrwGKpsNvp.GlnsDa7X4VIqS'}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/9h9h)

Comment: Please share the code for the `User` model.  What do you think "Data too long for column 'password' at row 1" might mean?

Comment: I just put password = Column (String (100)) so it's not too much for the column?

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to include any codes involved in this error.

But, this line of code

```
hashed_password= bcrypt.hashpw(user.password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
```

**Generated a string (a hash) that longer than your model can accommodate.**

The size you specified for the password attribute isn't large enough for that hash.

Answer (score 0):

**How ​​I solved it**

I resolved this problem in flask by changing the type of the password column from **VARCHAR** to **LONGTEXT**, which was currently **VARCHAR**.

**Practice:**

Access the phpmyadmin panel and choose the table where the password field is located and go to **structure**, then click on **change** in the desired field and change the type to LONGTEXT, save.

Now your password field supports long passwords.